# How to apply 2 animations on a single subview one after other iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

i have a button representing a fav button.
i want to animate it upward with 1.0 sec delay and then downward in 0.2 sec delay when some one click on it.
i have made two different methods to do upward and downward animation.
But when i actually run the code both animations commit at the same time which shows a reverse order. i want to animate the upward animation first and then downward animations.
here is the code.

```
-(void)starButtonUpAnimation{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];

    CGRect frame = self.starButton.frame;
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y - frame.size.height;
    self.starButton.frame = frame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

-(void)starButtonDownAnimation{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];

    CGRect frame1 = self.starButton.frame;
    frame1.origin.y = frame1.origin.y + frame1.size.height;
    self.starButton.frame = frame1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Button Action method where i am invoking above methods.

```
- (IBAction)clickedStarButton:(id)sender {
    [self starButtonUpAnimation];
    [self changeStarButtonImage];

    [self starButtonDownAnimation];
}
```

Comment: Start by replacing your old deprecated code with the modern block-based `UIView` animation methods. That will make things much simpler.

Comment: But i guess in that block based animation every iteration of animation will take same duration time. isn't so??

Comment: No, you specify the duration you want for each block.

Comment: can you please tell me how can we do this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some thing like this?

```
-(void)starButtonUpAnimation{

  CGRect frame = self.starButton.frame;
  frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y - frame.size.height;
  self.starButton.frame = frame;
}


-(void)starButtonDownAnimation{


  CGRect frame1 = self.starButton.frame;
  frame1.origin.y = frame1.origin.y + frame1.size.height;
  self.starButton.frame = frame1;

  }

- (IBAction)clickedStarButton:(id)sender {

  [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
      [self starButtonUpAnimation];
   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
     [self changeStarButtonImage];
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
        [self starButtonDownAnimation];
     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // clean up 
     }];
   }];
}
```

Comment: Just put the whole `UIView animateWithDuration...` chunk of code inside the `clickedStarButton:` method.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Now it works just the way i wanted.